# Getting 302 error while loading javascript library in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import one javascript library in my react project. I am getting the  302 status on the Network panel.

I can see the status 302  ( Not to be modified) in the  dev toolbar on browser Netwrok tab.
Can anyone let me know the cause of this issue ?.

Comment: 302 is "found": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302  Why do you think this is specific to React?  How are you importing your library?  (share the code)

Comment: I don't think there are enough details in this question to help you. You should provide a small example of your code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not react related it is due to Ajax request.Which is returned by server.

HTTP 302 is used for redirection. My guess is that there is some sort of server error and you are being redirected to an error page using 302. Check the server logs for errors.

Else try the following,

Adding a custom header to the response:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH","1");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Or:

Binding a JavaScript function to the ajaxSuccess event and checking to see if the header exists:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (request.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1') {
       window.location = '/';
    }
});
```